# Give default properties to component by directive in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In my angyular 6 project, I want to create any component with default properties. Because, there will be always same in my project. So, I learnt that `directive` can achieve this. But I don't know, how I can write this `directive`?

For example for calendar

**My Calendar (PrimeNg)**

```
<p-calendar [locale]="tr" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
```

**But, I want like below**

```
<p-calendar appCalendar></p-calendar>
```

**calendar-directive.ts**

```
 @Directive({
      selector: '[appCalendar]'
    })
    export class CalendarDirective {

      constructor() { }

      getDefaultProperties() { 
          var properties= { locale: 'tr', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}; ??????
          return properties; ????????
      };
    }
```

**I know, I also can make by new custom component.** But calendar has 40 property. So, I can't use any of them, if I write custom component like below. Forexample, in below, I can't give minDate or maxDate propery.

```
<my-custom-calendar>
    <p-calendar [locale]="tr" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
</my-custom-calendar>
```

Comment: You could try dependency injection where you can access parent component and then you are able to pass properties there https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree

Comment: I read your post. But, I  couldn't understand how can I apply for my example. Can you explain please? Because, I'm newbie at angular. @Sergey

Comment: You may try to extend `p-calendar` component

Comment: How can I extend p-calendar @veben. Is it like this ??? `<my-custom-calendar>
    <p-calendar [locale]="tr" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
</my-custom-calendar>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply write a directive which has the same selector as the ng-prime component, inject the component in this directive, and set defaults from there:

Here's [an example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pljnrvokrqg?file=app%2Fmy-progress.directive.ts) showing this in action with an [ng-bootstrap progress bar](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar/examples):

```
import { Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbProgressbar } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Directive({
  selector: 'ngb-progressbar' // same selector as the ng-bootstrap progressbar component. It could be an attribute, but then you would have to add an attribute to apply these defaults
})
export class MyProgressDirective {
  constructor(bar: NgbProgressbar) { // NgbProgressbar is the actual type of the component to customize, from ng-bootstrap
    bar.type = 'danger';
    bar.showValue = true;
    bar.animated = true;
    bar.striped = true;
  }
}
```

ng-bootstrap has a [dedicated mechanism](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/progressbar/examples#config) to apply custom defaults to every component, which is much more elegant though. You could suggest ng-prime to adopt such a mechanism, which is extremely useful.

Comment: This is, what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @JBNizet. It works. Is this method in acceptable for real world or tricky? Because I will use in a big project. And I'm afraid of disadvantage.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, and IMO ng-prime should provide a way to provide default values globally. But since it doesn't that's probably the easiest thing you can do.

Comment: Thanks again @JBNizet